# Where does the normal force in a vertical circular motion of a car in vertical road loop come from?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

i have to use it in calculation but i am confused whether it is just used for simplification like centrifugal force?
As there is no centrifugal force, the body is not 
pushing towards the edge of circle from inertial refrence then how can be normal force created which is usually the atomic repulsion force when the surface is pushed.

Comment: do you actually mean vertical, as in a roller coaster going through a loop, or did you intend horizontal, as a car driving in a circle on a flat road?

Comment: vertical as in a roller coaster

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the normal force comes from atomic-scale compression.  The principle of inertia (Newton's first law) tells us that the object wants to continue in a straight line.  But in this case, the car is on a vertically curved road.   It cannot continue in a straight line.  But it still "tries" to, and it's inertia carries it into the curve, compressing the surface of the road.  That compression applies a force onto the car changing its direction, and circular motion ensues.

Answer (score -1):

On a vertical roller coaster loop the normal force would be the force of the rails against the centrifugal force of the coaster Any mass moving in a circular motion has centrifugal force. Therefore in a vertical road loop the normal force would be the road surface resisting the centrifugal force of the cars mass exerted through the tires. Centrifugal force is considered a pseudo, or fictitious force. In this case it is the inertial force of the car's trajectory being changed  by the curved road's normal force.